# jmeter4.0_ getting junk value as response in view results tree of jmeter

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7HYj.png)I am learning jmeter (jmeter 4.0), i am facing below issue.
I am recording the script in jmeter, getting junk value as response in view result Tree of jmeter.
Please help me with it.

Response:
[image]

Comment: I fixed the formatting.

Comment: Sampler result tab. Please show what's on it.

Comment: Sampler result tab also has junk value as response

Comment: Could you please let me know how to format it